# document.location error handling

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I have the following Javascript.  The document.location statement produces an error as the URL does not exist.  I thought that a try/catch block would catch any errors.  However, this does not work.  Any ideas how I avoid this error and to continue processing the rest of the script?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function foo() 
{
  try
  {
    document.location='non-existing-site.com';
  }
  catch(err)
  {
  }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you change the location you just redirected...
The error handling needs to be in the new page.  In your example in `'non-existing-site.com'`
The HTML and javascript of the previous page is irrelevant at this point.

You can open the new page in a child window if you like to (Though pop-up is Yuck...)

```
var newWindow = window.open('non-existing-site.com', "windowName");
```

Comment: How can you put your script to domain you don't control, and especially to a non-existing domain?

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky. Who said it's a different domain? and by the way, it can be done. check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U6KHR/1/). It's not ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as this statement simply redirects the page to the address and this script will be unloaded. You can use XMLHttpRequest if you want to check an URL. Here is an example http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call